# How many connections can Oracle Express Edition (XE) handle?

Tags: oracle-xe

I'm building a web application that uses Oracle Database 10g as the database backend. I realize the Express edition has limitations, but I just wanted to make sure that number of connections wasn't one of them.

Does Oracle Express Edition (XE) limit the amount of concurrent connections (for example, the number of users viewing the site)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to:
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1673347
(among others)

There's no *hardcoded* limit, however there is an effective default limit of ~20 concurrent connections, however you can extend that with something like:
`ALTER SYSTEM SET processes=200 scope=spfile`
(and restart the DB)

In practice you've probably either hit other XE limits well before 200 connections, or should have been using a simpler DB to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

There are some benchmarks for XE 10g here:

http://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2011/03/stress-testing-oracle-xe-10g.html

Answer (score 1):

Number of connections depends on RAM and other dependant things.